# jQuery nested div Id loop

Tags: jquery, loops, html, nested, accordion

I have the following jQuery function doing a slideToggle on nested div ids

```
    jQuery("#100011000110001>#level0>#level3").live('click',function(){
        jQuery("#10001100011000110001>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110002>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110003>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110004>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110005>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110006>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110007>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110008>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110009>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110010>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110011>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110012>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110013>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110014>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110015>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110016>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110017>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110018>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110019>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110020>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110021>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110022>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
        jQuery("#10001100011000110023>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
});
```

where #10001100011000110001 etc... are the children divs of the parent div #100011000110001

Can someone tell me what kind of loop i can use to replace the repetitive lines of each nested child

Thx in advance

Comment: Ahh my eyes :) Give those div's a common class!

Comment: Since you can identify elements by their `id` you can ignore the ancestor elements and select by the `id` that you apparently know. You have invalid HTML, if you have *any* elements sharing an `id`; an `id` ***must be unique within the document***. Also, `live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and *removed entirely* in jQuery 1.9 (and above); it's been replaced by `on()`.

Comment: Thx for the deprecation info David

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly, the only thing you basically want is:

```
$("#level3").on('click',function(){
  var $level4 = $('#level4');
  for (var i=0; i<20; i++) {
    $level4.slideToggle("slow");
  }
});
```

Comment: This wont work. $level4 will only be one element youre just gonna slideToggle it 20 times. The problem is he has too many divs iwth the same ID

Comment: An ID can only occur once right? So -apart from that it doesn't make much sense to me- this is the correct translation of the given code by Michael Miguel.

Comment: I dont think he knows that though. Look at his code each of the selectors are pointing to a different div with the same ID.

Comment: Oh good point. The html is invalid since `level4` and `level10` is used repeatedly as an id. Those should be classes.

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe to assume `level10` id is only used in relevant divs?

```
  jQuery("*>#level0>#level4").slideToggle("slow")
```

Comment: Anthony I have #level0>#level4 children with different parents and I want to select only the appropriate children

Answer (score 0):

Replace them with an implicit loop. give all of level4 a class of "level4" then select it by class.

```
$(".level4").slideToggle("slow");
```

this will loop over all elements that match the ".level4" selector and slidetoggle each one.